# How should my question be tagged

Tags: discussion, tagging, specific-question

I have a question about my Mathematics Stack Exchange post: [A math/beauty question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3390465/a-math-beauty-question)

How should this question be tagged?

Comment: Probably the main reason you cannot find proper tags is because your question is not about math...

Answer (score 4):

I added the tag [music-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music-theory), which seemed fitting, and kept [relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relations) and [discrete-mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discrete-mathematics), since those seemed like a reasonable choice.

I removed [complex-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-analysis), which seems not related; this tag is for the study of functions of complex numbers, and not about analyzing complex problems.

I also removed [elementary-set-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-set-theory) as it does not seem very related to it either.